# Why is the answer to this recursive function 8?

Tags: java, recursion

This is a simple recursion problem that I've been stuck on for a while now. Basically I understand how f(4) would return f(3) + f(3), and these would return f(2) + f(2) + f(2) + f(2). However, if these are all being added together, wouldn't the answer be greater than 8? I am new to recursion and still trying to wrap my head around the concept.

```
public class test{
    
    public static int f(int n){
        if(n <= 1){
            return 1;
        }
        return f(n-1)+f(n-1);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(f(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to grab pen and paper and see what it would return when the input is 0, 1, 2  and 3. At that point I think it should become clear how it works.

Comment: How would the result be greater than 8?

Comment: You can see the visual execution [here](https://shorturl.at/kyH58)

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks I just got to the TinyURL site from your link. Please check it out.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks Then how do I follow it? I just don't find any form of the big link.

Comment: @NomadMaker It's generally redirect, [Here](https://pastebin.com/HCpxmgPb)  you found big link

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at this from the other direction.

```
f(1) = 1
f(2) = f(1) + f(1) = 2
f(3) = f(2) + f(2) = 2 + 2 = 4
f(4) = f(3) + f(3) = 4 + 4 = 8
```

From this, we can see the answer is 8.  If you expected a different answer, what answer did you expect, and how did you arrive at that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is always `f(n) = 2^(n-1)`

`f(4) = 2^(4-1) = 2^3 = 8`

Answer (score 0):

If you break up the calls into separate statements, it can be easier to see.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(f(4));
}
    
public static int f(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int r = f(n - 1);
    int s = f(n - 1);
    System.out.println("(r + s) = " + (r + s));
    return r + s;
}
```

Prints

```
(r + s) = 2
(r + s) = 2
(r + s) = 4
(r + s) = 2
(r + s) = 2
(r + s) = 4
(r + s) = 8
8
```

Different people respond to different outputs so you can alter with your own print statements.  I usually find the most useful way to understand logic flow for any program is to simply write down the state of each step on paper and work it thru that way.